# Where in the iPhone file system is iPhone's "Photo Library" found?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

In the file system on the iPhone, Photos are located under /User/Media/DCIM/*

But where should I found Images of "Photo Library" ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User/Yourusername/Pictures/iPhoto Library

Control+ Click on iPhoto Library to expose the dialog box that includes Show Package Contents

Click this

Click Masters

That's where the images are

BEWARE.. don't manually move or delete these files. They are part of an XML database structure which you will screw up if you fiddle with individual files. This is the reason Apple keeps them 'hidden'

Comment: I found it weird this answered your question @sugar. From my point of view, you asked the location of the photo library inside iPhone and this gives you the location on the synced desktop. Anyway, it is fine to copy it.

Comment: I concur with Cawas.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are still wondering where it is located inside your iPhone, as I just [answered elsewhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7845/deleting-photos-from-an-iphone/7889#7889), this is the place: `/private/var/mobile/Media/Photos/` all files inside that folder are relevant. The actual photo data are stored on the `Thumbs` encoded as `ithmb`. You'll need some software to decode them.

---

/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Sync/ is the correct path to "Photo Library"

Answer (score 1):

photos are usually stored in 2 folders in iPhone 4 Photos Albums: 
(1) Camerca Roll (2) Photo Library

I use "iPhone Explorer" application (on my Mac, not sure if there's a version for Windows), and get to my "Photo Library" photos by going into:

Root/User/Media/Photos/Thumbs

In above directory, each picture is stored in a separate folder (at least this is so on my iPhone 4).

Answer (score 0):

ok so I also found my Photo Library (not cameral roll) in /private/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Sync/100SYNCD if anyone is still having troubles!